# For which value $b$ line $t...y_1=x+b$ is a tangent line to the curve $y=\frac{x}{x+4}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

For which value $b$ line $t...y_1=x+b$ is a tangent line to the curve $y=\frac{x}{x+4}$?

My idea:
First find a derivative of $y$. $$y'=\frac{4}{(x+4)^2}$$
If line $t=ax+b$ is a tangent line of $y$, then $y'(x)=a$. So I need to find  for which $x$, $y'(x)=1?$
$$\frac{4}{(x+4)^2}=1$$
$$4=x^2+8x+16$$
$$x^2+8x+12=0$$
$$x_1=-6,x_2=-2$$
To find y value I need to plug x value in y.
$$y(-2)=-1$$
$$y(-6)=3$$
First $x=-2,y=-1$
$$-1=-2+b \to b=1$$
Second $x=-6,y=3$
$$3=-6+b \to b=9$$

Comment: So whats the problem

Comment: Is my work ok ?

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct. There are some issues of notation, for example I do not see why the variable $t$ is introduced. It would be maybe clearer to let the point(s) of tangency have $x$-coordinate $k$. Then we want $\frac{4}{(k+4)^2}=1$.